# Sometimes remote (via ssh) Linux shell script won't exit

Tags: linux, bash, shell, azure, ssh

I have some basic Linux shell scripts for deploying new Ubuntu VMs in Azure.

The deploy.sh script is run locally and it uses Azure CLI to create a VM. Next, it makes an ssh connection to the newly created VM and sends a script called cloud-init.sh which installs some packages. This script always runs fine with no issues.

However, when the cloud-init.sh script ends, it *sometimes* won't return control to the deploy.sh script. It may return immediately, in 10 minutes or never...

I've tried various methods of indicating that the script is done (you'll see them below) but none of them do the trick. Any ideas?

Here's the ssh command from the deploy.sh script:

```
ssh -o BatchMode=yes -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -T -i $SSHPEM $SSHUSERNAME 'bash -s' < cloud-init.sh
```

Here's the tail of the cloud-init.sh script:

```
echo "--------------------------------------------"
echo "cloud-init script ended at" $(date +"%T")
echo "--------------------------------------------"
exit 0
&
^D
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens exactly when the script fails to return control? Do you see that ended message? Does the terminal that ran the script respond to keypresses? Does hitting enter do anything? Does `ps` list the `ssh` process as still running?

Comment: I see this most often when the remote script has a file descriptor open (e.g., standard in, out, and/or error) or has an "X" connection active.  First, use the "-x" switch on the SSH command and ensure any programs started by the script have correctly redirected standard in, out, and error.

Comment: @EtanReisner Yes I see the ending message, but don't get a command prompt unless I CTRL-C. The terminal does respond to keypresses but they don't do anything. Pressing enter just adds new lines. Note, I'm using Putty on a Windows machine, connected to my local VM running Ubuntu. I run all of the scripts in this manner.

Comment: @RTLinuxSW I'll try that, and report if it works.

Comment: This is not a direct solution for your problem, but perhaps will allow you to workaround the issue (and perhaps not). I generally find VM extensions to be a better way to customize VM's. See http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/08/20/automate-linux-vm-customization-tasks-using-customscript-extension/